# Simple Admin functionality in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, admin

I want to add a admin functionality to my webapp with Rails version 3. I want something very simple, there will be only one admin, this funcionality doesn't need a username field, just a password field. I don't know how to do it, can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/21-super-simple-authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use scaffolding for generating form code and controller code.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding

and here is a simular question:
[Backend administration in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107674/backend-administration-in-rails)

hth

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [this Railscast on HTTP simple authentication](http://railscasts.com/episodes/82-http-basic-authentication):

```
# products_controller.rb
before_filter :authenticate

protected

def authenticate
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
    username == "foo" && password == "bar"
  end
end
```

As simple as that!

Comment: Thanks, pretty easy, but still it is not very much what a want. How can I add a form, I don't wanna use the bultin browser box. Any ideias?