# Rails 3 Admin Namespace Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm migrating the majority of my application to the admin namespace and while there are lots of guides related to this, I still can't manage. I've been primarily following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107674/backend-administration-in-rails/107736#107736Class)), along with any results Google brings up (they all tend to agree). Could somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong so I don't lose any more sleep?

Here is the error message:

> wrong argument type Module (expected Class)

```
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/admin/admin_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
app/controllers/admin/home_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

**routes.rb**

```
namespace :admin do 
  root :to => "home#index"

  resources :users
end
```

**admin/admin_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::AdminController < ApplicationController
```

**admin/home_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::HomeController < Admin::AdminController
```

**admin/users_controller.rb**

```
class Admin::UsersController < Admin::AdminController
```

I'm mostly sure it's something simple to related to the module and controller interaction, so I haven't included any other code. However, I should have found the solution by now and please let me know if any additional code is required.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe class Admin::AdminController < ::ApplicationController

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the reverse problem "wrong argument type Class (expected Module)" and it turned out there was a helper defined as a Class instead of a Module, so try searching for classes that are inadvertently defined as modules.  Like a controller defined as a Module.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you rename `Admin::AdminController` to `Admin::BaseController`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have something defined as `Admin` constant?
Try a fresh app with the same structure then add pieces from the current one and see where it breaks (Not so great suggestion, huh?).

I use the same organization for admin as you pasted...

Answer (score 0):

"wrong argument type Module (expected Class)"

This means you are defining a 'class' but that name is already defined as a 'module' somewhere else.  Search for what that could be...

Answer (score 0):

Can u follow the below code, Your controllers are fine, can you use the routes I have specified here.

```
 class Admin::AdminController < ApplicationController


 class Admin::UsersController < Admin::AdminController
```

This is same as what you have written, I think so.

```
namespace :admin do
   resources :users do as_routes end
end
root :to => "home#index"
```

Answer (score 0):

@Russell, I got that problem having created model AdminHelper (meant to contain admin help messages) :)

be careful in naming things!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered such problem when I used paperclip's has_attached_file with invalid parameters.