# Namespace, static pages, and inherited controllers, what files in what folders?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, namespaces, controller, routes

I'm building an admin control panel (attempting to ;) ).

I have been looking at [Backend administration in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107674/backend-administration-in-rails) and as suggested I am trying to make Admin::AdminController that checks for admin and sets the layout etc.

But I'm also trying to set a route in it that routes /admin to /admin/dash

From my understanding of reading http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing , specifically section 2.6,

Admin::AdminController

tells rails that Admin is the name space, AdminController is the controller which is a subclass (extension?, implementation of the interface?) of ApplicationController. Which would imply the controller should live in app/controllers/admin/ and be called admin_controller.rb.

But what I want is

AdminController

I get errors like:

```
uninitialized constant Admin::Controller
```

My code for the route:

```
  match :admin, :to => 'admin/admin#dash'
  namespace :admin do
    # Directs to /admin/resources/*
    match '/dash', to: '#dash'
    resources :users, :pictures
  end
```

I have put the controller in app/controllers/admin, app/controllers and the combinations with

```
class Admin::AdminController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :admin_user
  # / ** STATIC ADMIN PAGES ** /
  def dash
  end
end
```

or class AdminController < ApplicationController.

Edit: Maybe it's my understanding of routing. 
Example:

```
namespace :admin do
  get "/dash"
```

vs.

```
namespace :admin do
  match "/dash" to "admin#dash"
```

vs.

```
namespace...
  match "/dash" to "#dash"
```

The first one makes it so i can display a dash via the controller, i.e. admin/dash would be controlled by

```
AdminController < ApplicationControler
  def dash
  end
```

Does the second one route admin/admin/dash to admin/dash?

TL/DR:
I think my confusion comes from syntax or my poor understanding of RESTful practices or maybe even class / object inheritance in ruby.

Thanks for helping this n00b out. :)

Side question: can I change my code to be minimized until someone opens it like a spoiler so it doesn't crowd things up if I find more information and add it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your initial approach was correct, but you need to change it a little.

1) insert the /admin => /admin/dash inside the namespace (imho, its better to redirect it)

```
match 'admin' => redirect('admin/dash')
```

or

```
namespace :admin do
  match '/', to: 'admin#dash'
end
```

2) You can't match '/dash' to '#dash' since you're not inside a **resource** block, you're inside a **namespace** block, so it doesnt' have implied controller.

```
namespace :admin do
  match 'dash', to: 'admin#dash'
  # This will go to Admin::AdminController#dash
  # (first Admin because of the namespace,
  #  and the second because of the controller name)
end
```

hope it works :D

Comment: Awesome, this is a great explanation of what each name does! Why do you prefer redirect?

Comment: I don't like two URLs to have the same functionality, but its probably because I come from the world of SEO. Both solutions (redirect or not) are equally good.

Comment: Would it be better if I just picked one?

Comment: you need to pick one :) if you use the **redirect()**, when you go to `example.com/admin`, it will redirect to `example.com/admin/dash`, if you use **match '/'**, `example.com/admin` will display the same content as `example.com/admin/dash`

Comment: Ahh ok thanks! I ended up just redirecting to /admin, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is "scope" in routing.

```
scope "/admin" do
  resources :articles
end
```

Which will route /admin/articles to ArticlesController (without Admin:: prefix)

Documentation covers almost every possible case.
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: If you're taking this approve, I reckon you'll need to remove the **Admin::** namespace from **AdminController**