# 2 controllers,1 shared view - how to use form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have 1 model which is used by 2 controllers - 1 by normal user and 1 by admin user. New/create, edit/update actions are the same in both controllers. I have a shared view which is used by all of the actions but the problem is with form_for in that shared view:
For normal user I would have to use:

```
form_for @my_model, do |f|
```

For admin I would have to use:

```
form_for [:admin, @my_model] do |f|
```

How can I reuse the view with 2 controllers? Maybe there is a better way of designing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your design pattern is the best. I suppose you are using partial to share the view, you can actually pass a `locals` parameter in your partial `render`:

```
# user
<%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :zone => @my_model } %>

# admin
<%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :zone => [:admin, @my_model] } %>

# your form_for tag in the shared view
form_for(zone) do |f|
```

I'm not sure if this works, but hope it gives you a heads-up.

You should try using [admin namespace method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107674/backend-administration-in-rails) for this.

Comment: I actually am using admin namespace, just had a problem with passing locals to the view. Awesome stuff, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should recall [partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, your controllers are basically the same (New/create, edit/update).
 I would suggest adding a [before_filter](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods/before_filter) which tests if the user is an admin and only then gives access to the destroy action. 
(I'm guessing this is the method which differs).

```
#Controller
before_filter :admin => :only => [:destroy]
```